# how to set overflow:hidden in body after given height not after viewport height?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a page in which I have set the height of the `<body>` to 800px but actually the content is more then `800px`.

I want body should show content upto `800px` after that content should hide but the problem is if I use `overflow:hidden` in body it hide's all the content out of the viewport but my viewport height is `678px` so I want the scroll should come upto 800px.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.block{
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle with problem : https://jsfiddle.net/0b6g6886/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it works on body.  Try putting all the block div's within a containing div, and sent the same styles against this.  I updated the fiddle to show you

https://jsfiddle.net/0b6g6886/1/

```
.blocks {
  height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}



<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
 </div>
```

As per the note to say that the div's need to be directly in the body section with no wrapping div, this is a little hacky, but you could play with something like this:

```
body:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:800px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

This will overlay the divs with a white section, covering it.

Either that or use jQuery to add a div around it (if you can add jQuery):

```
$('body').prepend('<div class="blocks">');
$('body').append('</div>');
```

You can then style as above.

Comment: I can't set it to additional div. I am forced to do it on body

Comment: perhaps use jQuery to insert a div before and after?  they you can style those...  I don't believe you can do it at all on the body as you can other elements...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this on the `<body>` tag.

Wrap everything in a 'wrapper' div and it works as you expect:

https://jsfiddle.net/0b6g6886/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>  
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block{
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I can't set it to additional div. I am forced to do it on body.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add DIV inside body tag. give height to DIV inside the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .bod{
                   height: 800px;
                   overflow: scroll;

                }
                .block{
                    background: #000;
                    height: 100px;
                    width: 100%;
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="bod">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```